# Login php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I have a  problem with a login page. I talk about problem. If i try to login page he give a me perfect result when he  work on local but when a page is online don't find anything in query mysqli. When a query without a password he work well;

```
<?php
    session_start();// come sempre prima cosa, aprire la sessione
    require ("library/include/configurazione.php"); // Include il file di connessione al database
    $matricola = $_POST['matricola'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query_utente= mysqli_query($conne,"SELECT * FROM operatore WHERE matricola='".$matricola."'  ");  //per selezionare nel db l'utente e pw che abbiamo appena scritto nel log
    // Con il SELECT qua sopra selezione dalla tabella users l utente registrato (se lo è) con i parametri che mi ha passato il form di login, quindi
    // Quelli dentro la variabile POST. username e password. 

   if (mysqli_num_rows($query_utente)==true) { 
       $_SESSION["matricola"] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne,$_POST["matricola"]); // con questo associo il parametro username che mi è stato passato dal form alla variabile SESSION username
       $_SESSION["sede"] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne,$_POST["sede"]);
       $_SESSION["password"] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne,md5($_POST['password'])); // con questo associo il parametro username che mi è stato passato dal form alla variabile SESSION password
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_utente);     // metto i risultati dentro una variabile di nome $row
       $_SESSION["logged"] = true;  // Nella variabile SESSION associo TRUE al valore logged
       header("location:modules/root/dashboard.php");
   }
   else{
       echo "Errore ... Operatore non trovato"; // altrimenti esce scritta a video questa stringa di errore
   }
?>
```

but if i cange a query with password camp he don't work

```
$query_utente= mysqli_query($conne,"SELECT * FROM operatore WHERE matricola='".$matricola."' AND password='".$password."' ");
```

Comment: Please be aware that `md5()` is [**highly insecure**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) (even with a salt) and [should **NOT** be used for password storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908/159932). Instead, you should consider [**`password_hash()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [**`password_verify()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) along with a secure algorithm like `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` or `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`.

Comment: For `mysqli_real_escape_string` to be somewhat effective it needs to be used in the SQL context. You are only using it to store an escaped string in the session (also why store the password in the session?)

Answer (score -1):

Can you review the contents of your `library/include/configurazione.php` ? Maybe you need to configure your Database_server,Database_username,Database_password,and Database_name. Make sure that your database is connected on your website.

```
 <?php

$dbServername = ""; //servername
$dbUsername = ""; //database username
$dbPassword = ""; //database password
$dbName = ""; //database name

//Create connection
$conne = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if (!$conne) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "<!--Connected db successfully-->";

?>
```

also i modified your code. try this one

```
   <?php
   $matricola = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne, $_POST['matricola']);
   $password =  md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conne, $_POST['password']));

   $query_utente= mysqli_query($conne,"SELECT * FROM operatore WHERE 
   matricola='$matricola' AND password ='$password'");  
   $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($query_utente);

  if ($resultCheck > 0) { 
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_utente); 
   $_SESSION["matricola"] = $row['matricola'];
   $_SESSION["sede"] = $row['sede'];
   $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password']; 
   $_SESSION["logged"] = true;  
   header("location:modules/root/dashboard.php");
   }
   else{
   echo "Errore ... Operatore non trovato"; // altrimenti esce scritta a 
   video questa stringa di errore
  }
  ?>
```

but i recommend you to use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.